# How to call a Web Service through PLSQL with an input and output?

Tags: oracle, api, web-services

I need to establish a web service call within a procedure. Need help figuring out the follwing two.

1. A JSON data will need to be passed to the web service and the web service will return a JSON data as well.
2. If I execute my below code, I will get ORA-29261: bad argument error.

   ```
   declare
      l_req   utl_http.req;
   begin
   utl_http.set_proxy('https://username123:password123@ouf.ty.tty.ngs:11235/w/call',80);
   l_req:= utl_http.begin_request
            ( 'https://username123:password123@ouf.ty.tty.ngs:11235/w/call'
            , 'POST'
            , 'HTTP/1.1'
            );
   end;
   ```

Comment: commend out the l_req function call, do you still get the error? if so, problem is with the set_proxy call. you're not sharing with us the line number, so we have to guess which call is borked to start with

Comment: @thatjeffsmith yes, the error was from the set_proxy call.

Answer (score 0):

SET_PROXY expects two strings, and you're passing it a string and an INT

```
PROCEDURE set_proxy(proxy            IN VARCHAR2,
                    no_proxy_domains IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL);
```

> SET_PROXY Procedure This procedure sets the proxy to be used for
> requests of the HTTP or other protocols, excluding those for hosts
> that belong to the domain specified in
> no_proxy_domains.no_proxy_domains is a comma-, semi-colon-, or
> space-separated list of domains or hosts for which HTTP requests
> should be sent directly to the destination HTTP server instead of
> going through a proxy server.